# Unfolding a proof term in Coq

Tags: coq

I wonder if there is a way to obtain the proof term (serialized via `Print` or not) at some level beyond the current context (or just down to primitives). For example, executing the following

```
From mathcomp Require Import odd_order.PFsection14.
Print Feit_Thompson.
```

results in

```
Feit_Thompson = 
fun (gT : fingroup.FinGroup.type)
  (G : fingroup.group_of (gT:=gT)
         (ssreflect.Phant
            (fingroup.FinGroup.arg_sort
               (fingroup.FinGroup.base gT)))) =>
BGsection7.minSimpleOdd_ind no_minSimple_odd_group (gT:=gT)
  (G:=G)
     : forall (gT : fingroup.FinGroup.type)
         (G : fingroup.group_of (gT:=gT)
                (ssreflect.Phant
                   (fingroup.FinGroup.arg_sort
                      (fingroup.FinGroup.base gT)))),
       is_true
         (ssrnat.odd
            (fintype.CardDef.card
               (T:=fingroup.FinGroup.arg_finType
                     (fingroup.FinGroup.base gT))
               (ssrbool.mem
                  (finset.SetDef.pred_of_set
                     (fingroup.gval G))))) ->
       is_true (nilpotent.solvable (fingroup.gval G))
```

but i would like to unfold the identifiers (theorems and definitions) used in the proof term such as `no_minSimple_odd_group` to their proof terms. I suspect that the opacity of theorems and lemmas might pose an obstacle to this purpose.

The naive solution i can think of is to recursively query each identifier via `Print`. Or a less naive (and less ideal due to the change in the language representing the proof term) solution, via program extraction.

Comment: Would `Print All Dependencies Feit_Thompson.` be of any help?

Comment: definitely helpful for recursively printing (my naive solution) but I don't think this shows the proof terms (lambda terms) by itself.

Comment: You might find [this](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2016-11/msg00062.html) coq-club's thread useful. They mention the [template-coq](https://github.com/gmalecha/template-coq) plugin.

Comment: @AntonTrunov this is indeed interesting! thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there is a direct way of doing that, but it wouldn't be too hard to implement, at this level opacity is just a flag and can be bypassed.

However, I wonder about what do you want to achieve?

Note that most proof terms obtained that way are going to be just unmanageable, specially unfolding will quickly lead to a worse than exponential size blowup.

Comment: yes, they could be very big depending on the set of constants the unfolding stops at, but i want to be able to inspect the same proof term given different sets of primitives (constants).

Comment: After having a quick look I'm almost sure that you will have to write a plugin extending the `Eval red` tactic to unfold even more if you want this functionality.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. i am curious about interacting with Coq programmatically (as an OCaml library?). could you suggest some references?